# owl carousel loop:true cannot applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I would like to implement the loop:true option in my owl carousel, but actually when I overwrite the old owl.carousel.min file the entire slider disabled, but it works fine with old version owl.carousel.min file without loop.

Can anyone help me how to overcome from this one.

```
$("#owl-example4").owlCarousel({
    navigation : true,
    navigationText: [
      "<i class='icon-chevron-left icon-white'><</i>",
      "<i class='icon-chevron-right icon-white'>></i>"
      ],
     autoPlay: 3500, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
    autoplayTimeout:2500,
    items :1,
    loop: true,
    singleItem: true,
    autoHeight: true,

    responsive: true,
    responsiveRefreshRate : 200,
    responsiveBaseWidth: window,
});
```

html as follows

```
<section class=".banner" id="banner"><!--main-section banner-->
    <div id="owl-example4" class="owl-carousel fadeInRight animated wow">
        <div class="item darkCyan text-center hpsliderimg1">
            <img src="img/slide1.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"/>
        </div>

        <div class="item darkCyan text-center hpsliderimg2">
            <img src="img/slide2.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"/>
        </div>

        <div class="item darkCyan text-center hpsliderimg3">
            <img src="img/slide3.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"/>
        </div>

        <!--<div class="item darkCyan text-center hpsliderimg4">
            <img src="img/slide-4.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
        </div>-->
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you please also share the relevant code parts?  That will make identifying the problem easier. And welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: @plamut    thanks for the reply sir

Comment: the above code works fine without loop, i googled and found that for loop i have to use newer version of owl-carousel.min.js hence i replace the old one with the new beta version, this leads to disable the carousel placed div

Comment: @prasad what you did in code

Comment: Please be sure to read the tag descriptions.  This question is not related to [tag:owl], the Web Ontology Language.  Also, it usually helps to add language and library tags (in this case, Javascript and jQuery).  I've edited your tags.

Comment: @sasijj I did format changes in your code, not more than that

Comment: @taylor thank you, i understood what you are saying hereafter i will follow this

Comment: @PrasadKhode thank you man because am newbie so i dont know how to do that all